# Using 'screen' to detach from GVIM

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I want to be able to detach a gui-window for a program like gvim.

I ssh into the remote machine, and launch 'screen':

```
screen
```

I'll then just launch "gvim" in this screen session. However, I cannot do a ctrl+a+d on the gvim, and when I kill the console from which the gvim was launched, it also kills the gvim window. When I reconnect to the screen session with 'screen -r' I see:

```
 X connection to serverNum:104.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't detach X apps with `screen`. It's for terminal programs only.

Use something like `xmove`, `vncserver`, `FreeNX` or Chrome Remote Desktop.